# Dots and black screen while gaming

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, cpu, gpu

I have a very annoying problem with my PC.

It's specifications are as follows:

- Model: **ASUS N55SF** Notebook
- Processor: **i7 2670QM 2.20 GHz**
- Graphics Card: **GT 555M 2 GB**

My issue is that I get black screen while gaming and dots appear that are sometimes red, sometimes green, and sometimes multiple colors. These dots are moving around on the left side of the screen. I need to shutdown the PC manually to get rid of the issue.

I've tried the following:

- Formatting the PC
- Cleaning the dust from my PC
- Changing thermal paste

I didn't have the problem for 2 weeks, but now the problem has started happening again.

Some additional info pertaining to the temperatures:

- The processor while gaming: 91°C max
- The GPU while gaming: 76°C max
- The processor under normal use: 40->50°C
- The GPU under normal use: 36->40°C

EDIT : Do you think baking the GPU is helpful to solve this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by "baking the GPU"?  That sounds bad.

Comment: Yes it's bad , nvm , but i found that when i shake my pc , the black screen disappear i do not understand :O !

Comment: Sounds like a bad connection.  If you took the laptop apart to change the paste then you probably didn't put it back together correctly.

Comment: I think so , but what should i put back together , if i open the laptop i want to be sure what to reconnect , what's exactly the cause of the problem , the screen ? , the gpu connexion ? ...

Comment: Any of the above.  Whatever you took apart before, do so again and be careful when putting it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually a defective GPU, or overclocking the GPU which accesses shaders/etc that are not working.

Basically the driver crashes so badly due to some unexpected hardware problem that the entire system crashes. If your pc is relatively new, see if your GPU still has waranty.

Try a different GPU to verify that the GPU is defective. Also try this GPU in another pc to make extra sure.

Comment: So why after doing these step the problem vanished for a while(2weeks) ?

   ; formating the pc
   ; cleanning the dust from my pc
   ; Changing thermal paste;
My pc is 2 years so there's no more warranty ..

Comment: Dunno. Also processor of 91C is very high. Might also be the cause. Try gaming with your computer case open so the air can be vented much better (and the processor will thus heat less quickly).

Comment: I tried by lowering the % of power the processor the temps go down to 83° and i got the same problem with the gpu so i don't think so it's related to the processor .. :/

Comment: The processor temperature is perfectly harmless. This is a notebook with a mobile CPU—spec’d for 100°C. Swapping the GPU is probably impossible.

Comment: @DanielB well, until just now, there was no way for me to know he was using a notebook. It does change thigns, but also explains why I suggested to open the case. Doesn't change the fact that 91C is still quite hot.

Comment: Yes, but rest assured, it’s a normal temperature. When I fire up a game on my X220t, I also reach 91°C (probably the throttling target) very quickly. The information on the system has always been in the question. ;)

Comment: It's sad i think there's no clue to resolve the problem , only by changing my pc :(

Answer (score 3):

Usually things like this boil down to high temps and/or hardware failures.  It might be the GPU itself, the GPU's fan, the case fan(s), or even just a borderline heat problem that is exacerbated by the room temperature.

You've cleaned the case out once and the problem went away for a couple weeks.  I'd say clean it out again and see if you can get some better air flow to the GPU.  Maybe the GPU fan needs replaced, maybe you have case fans that aren't working as well as they need to.  Heck, you might even have a situation where the ambient room temperature is getting to high for the fans to be effective.

Comment: Well it's a laptop so i got only one fan , now after your response and LPChip too it's sure that the problem comes from the gpu , but i don't think it's overheating , from the day i bought the pc to today the temps was the same :/

Comment: I didn't know until your comment that it was about a laptop. 91C is still very hot, but with a laptop thats hard to overcome.